# $.ajax send POST and receive JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to send a POST request to a PHP script which then will return a JSON string.

I am wondering if this is possible using `$.ajax` method?

Comment: Yes it's in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), surprisingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

And in PHP you can do this

```
<?php
$return = $_POST;
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: That will return something claiming to be an HTML document, so jQuery won't treat it as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return any data you like. Just make sure that you output the correct Content-Type [header](http://php.net/header).

Comment: so the json would come back in the data section right? success:(data)?

Comment: I guess I am wondering how I would parse it to do what I need to do with the JSON

Comment: For processing it on client side you may use eval() function (may be dangerous!) or some JSON parser library - I believe jQuery has one.

Comment: jQuery will parse it and populate `data` automatically.